# Как сделать из <input> dropdown?

Tags: css, bootstrap

Здравствуйте.
Использую [Bootstrap-4](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com) и есть задача сделать из  выпадающий список.

Реализовал поиск на бэкенде и автокомплит на фронтенде, но из-за очень слабых познаний в CSS, не получается реализовать выпадающий список.

На данном этапе есть только простая форма внутри навбара:

```
  <div class="m-b-1">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-md navbar-inverse bg-primary">
      <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control mr-sm-2" placeholder="Search" v-model="q" @input="typeInput">
          <search-item 
            v-for="item in search" 
            :item="item" 
            :key="item.id">  
           </search-item>
        </div>
        <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary my-2">Submit</button>
      </form>
     </nav>
    </div>
```

и примитивный шаблон элемента:

```
  <script type="text/x-template" id="search-item">
    <ul class="form-group row">
      <a :href="item.link" class="form-control-static"><li>
        #{ item.title }
      </li></a>
    </ul>
  </script>
```

Заранее спасибо.

P.S. Обещаю, что вызубрю CSS3 :)

Comment: a select не вариант?

Comment: @Duoxx, select был бы вариантом, если бы в него можно было вводить текст.

Comment: http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

Comment: не подойдет разве?

Comment: Это jQueryUI, который я не использую. Он работает с данными, которые находятся в javascript переменных. Я же отдаю запрос на бэкенд, а на клиент получаю результат. 

У меня всё работает. Сам автокомплит реализован. Не получается именно сверстать input таким образом, чтобы он был в виде выпадающего списка, со значениями, которые я туда кладу, при каждом изменении <input>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сделал следующим образом:

```
      <div class="btn-group">
        <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          <div class="dropdown-menu">
            <a href="" class="btn dropdown-item"></a>
          </div>
      </div>
```

При помощи JS, сюда `<div class="btn-group">` нужно добавлять `show`, когда элементы появляются, а `aria-expanded` нужно менять на `true`. И, соответственно, наоборот.